# header(); not functioning

Tags: php, sql

Before you mark this duplicate or mark down, please note none of the solutions I found online solved my problem. So I am trying to redirect people to **/home.php** after everything is uploaded.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
    include('head.php');
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $title = stripslashes($title);
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $title);
    $preview = $_POST['preview'];
    $preview = stripslashes($preview);
    $preview = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $preview);
    $thumbnail = $_POST['thumbnail'];
    $thumbnail = stripslashes($thumbnail);
    $thumbnail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $thumbnail);
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $category = stripslashes($category);
    $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $category);
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $content = stripslashes($content);
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $content);
    $content = str_replace('\r', '', $content);
    $content = str_replace('\n', '</p><p>', $content);
    $content = str_replace('</p><p> </p><p>', '</p><p>', $content);
    $content = str_replace('</p><p></p><p>', '</p><p>', $content);
    $content = str_replace('</p><p>\r\n</p><p>', '</p><p>', $content);
    $content = str_replace(' i ', ' I ', $content);
    //To capitalize I's.
    $author = $_SESSION['id'];

    if ($_SESSION['rank'] == 2) {
        $status = 1;
    }
    else {
        $status = 0;
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO article (title, preview, author, thumbnail, section, content, status) VALUES ('$title', '$preview', '$author', '$thumbnail','$category', '$content', $status)");
    if ($sql == true) {
        $section = strtolower($category);
        print $section;
        flush();
        header('location:/home.php');
    }
    else {
        print "Did not work.";
    }
?>
<style>
html {background: #FFFFFF;}
</style>
```

I know it has nothing to do with the html part because the code was not working before I added it in. I have all error reporting turned on so I have no idea what the problem is in my code.

Comment: You don't describe what the problem is

Comment: The problem is that the code acts as if header(); is not there.

Comment: `header("Location: FULLURL");` Field names are case-insensitive.

Comment: I'd really prefer to just be able to use relative URLs if at all possible.

Comment: give tit a test any way, make sure ther is a space after the colon. you can get the full url via code

Comment: Tried it out, didn't work.

Comment: then something 'else' is going on here are you sure the code even gets to that point? if the querry fails it could be stopping before the header line

Comment: I am sure that the query does not fail, I've tested it with an if statement in my code.

Comment: move the header call to the fist line, see if it works

Comment: Wait, what is this? `header('location: profile');` right after you declare $sql?

Comment: Took that park out completely. STILL DOESN'T WORK!!!

Comment: Anyone got any more solutions or is this page cursed?

Comment: does a header call in a page all by itself work? .. whats in head.php?

Comment: Yeah, it does work.

Comment: ok so slowly add this code in, untill you find what breaks it

Comment: you code above, one line at a time

Comment: I literally commented and uncommented every single line and nothing.

Comment: Ok so I used an 'or die' thing after header and it showed it. So there's something wrong with header itself.

Comment: 2 things. 1) Add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`. If your query fails, so will your header. 2) Are you running this as `file:///file.xxx` or as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or on a hosted site? You'll need to "ping" me to get my direct attention or any other by starting with the `@` symbol, followed by their name. Do that, then tell/ping me about those two points. Your `else {
        print "Did not work.";
    }` is not helping you; get the real error as I stated or as `else {
        print "Did not work." . mysqli_error($conn);
    }` - Try getting rid of `flush();` too.

Comment: I'm doing this on a website server.

Comment: I tried everything on there but nothing.

Comment: THIS IS ABSOLUTELY MADDENING

Comment: @J.DOe Btw, `$thumbnail = $_POST['thumbnail'];` suggests you're trying to handle a file here, and that is usuallly `$_FILES` and not `$_POST`. We have no idea what the HTML file looks like, or if it contains a "post" method. If it doesn't, then `<form>` defaults to a GET method and your code will/could fail silently because of it. My comment above was a 2-part; you answered "one". Plus, you didn't say if your query works or not. If it doesn't then MySQL will also fail silently if your column lengths are too short. There isn't anything I can say here; that's all that comes to mind.

Comment: Actually $thumbnail is just a URL.

Comment: Query works as well.

Comment: well I'm done, i would need direct access to debug this.

Comment: What is in head.php? I don't see reference to it in the thread (or maybe I missed it...it's a long thread)

Comment: `print $section;
        flush();
        header('location:/home.php');` you're outputting before header here. I now give up on your question; you say no errors, I find that rather hard to believe. Edit: @Dagon me too.

Comment: @Rasclatt I thought about it earlier, but the guy says the query works. *"Query works as well. – J. DOe 5 mins ago"* - It's probably connection stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `exit;` below the redirect.

```
header('location:/home.php');
exit;
```